# Apns notifications is not Working with Developement Certificate

Tags: java, cordova, ios5, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Please suggest me, As iam having developement p12 file and dependencies But iam getting Exceptiopn when sending notification through Developement Certificate.p12 file. the Exception is (javax.net.ssl.SSLException) javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error

```
package com.push.notification.server;

import com.notnoop.apns.APNS;
import com.notnoop.apns.ApnsService;
import com.notnoop.apns.EnhancedApnsNotification;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Date;

public class ApnsTest {

    private ApnsService service;

    public ApnsTest() {
    try {

        String path = "p12 file name";

        File certFile = new File(path);
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(certFile);
        service = APNS.newService().withCert(fis, "pwd")
            .withSandboxDestination()
            .build();
        sendMessage();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ApnsTest();
    }

    public void sendMessage() {
    String payload = APNS.newPayload().alertBody("nnnnn").sound("default").build();
    String deviceToken = "267fe9f23984cc6d8ca7b35db3c4b829cdbe2f9f1dbd3258cbbfa8f94e3fd986";
    int now = (int) (new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    EnhancedApnsNotification notification = new EnhancedApnsNotification(EnhancedApnsNotification.INCREMENT_ID(),
        now + 60 * 60, deviceToken, payload);

    System.out.println("Sending push notification");
    try {
        service.push(deviceToken, payload);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, above problem solved by Creating Development certificate once again.

This is procedure [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBqg0.gif) first in 
On your Mac, open Keychain Access

From the top menu, select

Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate From a Certificate Authority…

Fill out your email address, common name
Check Save to disk
Press Continue and save the .certSigningRequest file somewhere
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f5BY.gif)

Configuring Push Notifications for the App ID
Once the APP ID registration is completed, you need to configure it to make to work with push notification.
[enter image description here][3]
Select the App ID you just created, and click Edit
At Push Notifications, click Create Certificate then **Continue
Click Choose File… and upload the .certSigningRequest file you have generated and saved on your Mac earlier. Click Generate.
Once the certificate was generated, download it onto your Mac
[enter image description here][4]
1.4 Creating a Private Key
Now you are going to create a private key from the downloaded certificate.
[enter image description here][5]
Double-click the downloaded file. It should open in Keychain Access
Select My Certificates at left. You should find the certificate you just added.
Control-click the certificate, and select Export “Apple Development IOS Push Services:…”…
Save it as ..p12 file, by selecting File Format as Personal Information Exchange (.p12) in the Save As dialog

1.5 Creating a Provisioning Profile on Apple Developer portal,

Go to Provisioning Profiles

Click + to create a new provisioning file

Select iOS App Development, then Continue

Select a correct App ID from the drop-down list, then Continue

Select a correct certificate from the list, then Continue

Select devices you are going to develop with, the Continue

Enter a name for the provisioning profile, then Generate

Download the file

Double-click open the file in Xcode. The profile now should be added to Xcode.